# Spring cache Cache name must be non-null if specified excpetion

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache

I have been trying to implement a basic caching for my project but i am getting an error  while deploying the application .

Server : Tomcat 7

Spring Version : 4.1.4

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache name must be non-null if specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:162)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperation.setCacheNames(CacheOperation.java:66)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.SpringCacheAnnotationParser.parseCacheableAnnotation(SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.SpringCacheAnnotationParser.parseCacheAnnotations(SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java:67)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.SpringCacheAnnotationParser.parseCacheAnnotations(SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource$2.getCacheOperations(AnnotationCacheOperationSource.java:124)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource.determineCacheOperations(AnnotationCacheOperationSource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource.findCacheOperations(AnnotationCacheOperationSource.java:121)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.computeCacheOperations(AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.getCacheOperations(AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.java:100)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationSourcePointcut.matches(CacheOperationSourcePointcut.java:39)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:225)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 64 more
```

I tried using different cache manager configuration with no luck

here is the xml configuarion

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <set>
                <value>cache1</value>
                <value>cache2</value>
                <value>cache3</value>
            </set>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I also tried the config given on the spring docs

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="cache1"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="cache2"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

the function I am trying to cache

```
@Cacheable(value = "cache1", key = "#root.methodName")
    public List<ObjectDetails> getAllObjects() {
        return objectDao.getAllObjects();
    }
```

**Can any one point me towards where this issue might arise from while implementing caching.**

Comment: The exception does not match your code. I'd say you have defined a cache annotation with the  empty string as cache name.

Comment: I feel like an idiot ...you where right .....found one annotation with empty value .... Thanks Stéphane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Stéphane Nicoll I was able to find the issue

> Cache name must be non-null if specified

This means I have provided an empty string in place of cache name like this.

```
@Cacheable(value = "", key = "#root.methodName")
    public List<ObjectDetails> getAllObjects() {
        return objectDao.getAllObjects();
    }
```

Provided a suitable name and it was resolved . Thanks.